# ContentView not properly set on Android (Huawei device): maxScrollFactorString = null

Tags: android, listview, null

When I call setContentView(layout..) it switches to the layout. It only loads a TextView but not my ListView. I did *not* block the UI thread.

In LogCat there is a strange message: "maxScrollFactorString = null". The layout loads just fine in an emulator.

I did not find anything in Google and it seems to be a platform-/device-specific error.

Can anybody help? I need to know how I can make the layout load completely.

The device is a Huawei U8510 with stock Android 2.3.3.